# stored size in postgres increasing when spring boot (3.2) & hibernate (6.4.0.Final) upgraded

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

### Short story

Getting error `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object; (java.time.LocalDateTime and [Ljava.lang.Object; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

### Long story

I am upgrading the spring boot from 2.7.x to 3.2. I have upgraded by searching things online. but I made one change regarding one of the entity fields as below because my application was not starting.

```java
// old
@Column(name = "last_modified")
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime lastModified;

// new
@Column(name = "last_modified")
@JdbcType(BinaryJdbcType.class)
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime lastModified;
```

previous data stored in Postgres had `last_modified` column of size 51 bytes but after this change, new rows has a size of 430 bytes.

Using the below converter. here size is 51 bytes before putting into db & also getting out of db. But old data is causing issues.

```java
@Override
public Byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    log.info("Inside convertToDatabaseColumn");
    if (localDateTime == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try (final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer)) {
        oos.writeObject(localDateTime);
        log.info("buffer size: {}", buffer.size());
        return ArrayUtils.toObject(buffer.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        lalalalala
    }
}

@Override
public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(final Byte[] bytes) {
    // this line not executed in case of old data & works fine wit old data & gives 51 bytes
    log.info("Inside convertToEntityAttribute: {}", Array.getLength(bytes));
    if (bytes == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try (final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(bytes));
            final ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)) {
        final LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(objectInputStream.readObject().toString());
        return dateTime;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        lalalal
    }
}
```

### Other tried solutions

#### 1

If I dont add this JdbcType annotation, it fails to start & gives error `Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to determine SQL type name for column 'last_modified' of table 'resource': class org.hibernate.type.internal.CustomMutabilityConvertedBasicTypeImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType (org.hibernate.type.internal.CustomMutabilityConvertedBasicTypeImpl and org.hibernate.type.BasicPluralType are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.LaunchedClassLoader @37a71e93)"`

#### 2

I also found answer like below at some places but it is giving error at run time.

```
@Column(name = "last_modified", columnDefinition = "bytea")
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime lastModified;

// Error
// org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement [ERROR: column \"last_modified\" is of type bytea but expression is of type smallint[]"}
// Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression."}
```

### Versions

'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:3.2.0'
'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.5.4'
'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.4.0.Final'
Java 17

### Summary

- able to push new data & get new data from db but size in db is really big
- as old & new data has different size, giving error. `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object; (java.time.LocalDateTime and [Ljava.lang.Object; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found fix. So issue is `Byte` array when serialized not converting to `byte` array. This is strange, dont know why.

To fix this, made 2 changes. first in `Entity`, same as solution 2.

```java
@Column(name = "last_modified", columnDefinition = "bytea")
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime lastModified;
```

Then changed converter to use `byte` array instead of `Byte` array.

```java
@Override
public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    log.info("Inside convertToDatabaseColumn");
    if (localDateTime == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try (final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer)) {
        oos.writeObject(localDateTime);
        log.info("buffer size: {}", buffer.size());
        return buffer.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        lalalalala
    }
}

@Override
public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(final byte[] bytes) {
    if (bytes == null) {
        return null;
    }
    try (final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            final ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream)) {
        final LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(objectInputStream.readObject().toString());
        return dateTime;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        lalalal
    }
}
```